# Cisco QuickVPN Can't view local computers

Tags: networking, vpn, cisco, ipsec, cisco-vpn

I am connected to my QuickVPN connection to my RV180 VPN Router and I can access the router via IP but I can't find or see any of the computers. How can I fix that?

Do I need to do some more advanced setup? I can't seem to access the network shares.

EDIT: I also noticed that the IP on a "see my ip" google search shows the local network's IP and not the IP of the network I am VPN'ing into. Is that normal?

LOCAL NETWOKR: 10.30.0.0
VPN NETWORK: 192.168.10.0

IPCONFIG:

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : HOST-018
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : 
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : linksys
                                       host.host2.host3.us
                                       host.private

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : host.host2.host3.us
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 78-2B-CB-AC-CB-1F
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.30.20.0(Preferred) 
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Tuesday, November 26, 2013 8:54:04 AM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Wednesday, November 27, 2013 8:54:04 AM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.30.0.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.30.0.1
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 8.8.8.8
                                       x.164.64.x
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.host.host2.host3.us:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : host.host2.host3.us
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 9:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft 6to4 Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::1008:3876:f5dc:ebff%13(Preferred) 
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 318767104
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-19-D1-E5-26-78-2B-CB-AC-CB-1F
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

On the VPN I can access the VPN Router at 192.168.10.1 but not the machines via their names.

Comment: Frank, you're going to need to give us more info, like a drawing and some config info, along with test pings, routes, errors.

Comment: Done. Added pictures too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a routing issue on the client end. If you can ping the endpoint but nothing else, and a 'show my ip'-style site is still using the local IP, you're not making the VPN your default route.

If it's not desirable to send everything down the VPN, you at least need to add a route encompassing the remote IP range. The endpoint is connected with a /32, so you can ping the other side, but your machine doesn't know that the rest of 192.168.10/24 exists down the VPN.

Once you've done that, additionally make sure on the remote end of the connection that VPN clients are not VLAN'd off, and that client isolation by any other means is disabled.